# 'glGenBuffers' was not declared in this scope. Windows 7. Qt 4.8.1

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, glew

```
'glGenBuffers' was not declared in this scope
```

thats the error which I get after trying to use that metod. How to add appropriate libs or sth else and what i should add and how. I'm using win 7 and qt 4.8.1. I've read about GLEW but I don't know how to add it to windows or qt.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a FAQ. Windows defines the OpenGL ABI (B for binary interface) only up to version OpenGL-1.1 – anything beyond that must be loaded at runtime using the extension loading mechanism. Most easily done by using a wrapper library like [GLEW](http://glew.sourceforge.net).

> I've read about GLEW but I don't know how to add it to windows or qt.

If you want to use any 3rd party library, you've to learn how to do that. It boils down to install the library and its header in some system wide directory, but outside the regular compiler tree, and add those directories to the include and library search paths.

Comment: thx, but I've found that I can pass that problem by adding #include  <QGLFunctions> and  expanding my class that already inherits  from QGLWidget inherit from : "protected QGLFunctions"

Comment: @EmilSmęt But unfortunately [`QGLFunctions`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qglfunctions.html) only provides OpenGL ES 2.0 equivalent functionality, but this may be enough for your pruposes.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Removed it. However GLEW isn't up to modern standards as well.

Answer (score 2):

I use this code for including GLEW and Glut for cross-platform development:

```
#ifndef GL_H
#define GL_H

#ifdef __APPLE__
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLUT/glut.h>
#else
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#endif

#endif // GL_H
```

I encapsulate that into a file called gl.h and include that anywhere I need an OpenGL context. You will need to research how to install GLEW on your system. Make sure that you install the correct build of GLEW for your compiler. If you use Visual C++ 2010 or MinGW, it will be slightly different as far as where to put the libs and include files. You could always build from source too, but that is a more advanced route.

If you would like some sample code on how to get started with Qt and OpenGL, I've got a repository on Bitbucket with some code that I wrote for an OpenGL programming class here: https://bitbucket.org/pcmantinker/csc-4356/src/2843c59fa06d0f99d1ba90bf8e328cbb10b1cfb2?at=master